# File type check is not working

Tags: php

I have a problem with the file type check when uploading on server. My function is not working as it should. On the server is always uploaded absolutely everything. Please help me

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['ulozitzmeny'])) {

    $valid_mime_types = array(
        "image/gif",
        "image/png",
        "image/jpg",
        "image/jpeg",
    );

    if (in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], $valid_mime_types)) {

        $file = rand(1000, 100000) . "-" . $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
        $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
        $folder = "images";

        $new_size = $file_size / 1024;
        $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
        $final_file = str_replace(' ', '-', $new_file_name);

        if (move_uploaded_file($file_loc, $folder . $final_file)) {
            $sql = "UPDATE users SET file='$file', type='$file_type', size='$file_size' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user]'";
            mysql_query($sql);
        }
    }else{

        echo 'error';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Did your html tag form looks like this? <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> sometimes the *enctype* tag is missing.

Comment: Yes, my html tag form looks like this.

Comment: please check the output of your $_FILES and $_POST if the data you are trying to handle is the correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a much easier way to validate the type of file being uploaded. Use `fileinfo` to get the extension of the file being uploaded and then compare against permissible file extensions.

Here's the reference:

- [fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php)

Your code should be like this:

```
// your code

// valid file extensions
$valid_extensions = array("gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg");

// get the file extension
$ext = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));  // png

// now check against permissible extensions
if(in_array($ext, $valid_extensions)){
    // allowed
}else{
    // not allowed
}

// your code
```